# These 2 delegate usages, are they same?

Tags: objective-c

For example, I have A view and B view，some value is passing from A to B.

In `B.m`, I wrote:

```
A *av = [[A alloc] init];
[av setDelegate:self]
```

Is it the same as I wrote in `A.m`:

```
B *bv = [[B alloc] init];
[self setDelegate:bv];
```

Where should I put this "setDelegate"? in `viewDidLoad`? compiler didn't generate any error, but the value passing is not succeed, Can somebody give me some hints on it? Thanks

Comment: Seems to be a `[` missing in the second example?!?

Comment: I do think it should read `B *bv = [[B alloc]init];`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @UweKeim You're right -- fixed that.

Comment: oh,yea,soorry...shouldn't make that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the point of using a delegate is that the delegating object (`av` in this case) needs some sort of help from an external object. If that object sets its own delegate, as you do with `bv`, that sort of negates the advantage of having an external object. That is, if `A` knows that it wants an instance of `B` as its delegate, you might as well roll the code from `B` into `A` and skip the whole delegation business.

That said, it's possible that `A` might use `B` as its delegate by default, but still allow an instance of some other class to be set as the delegate in order to change certain behavior. If that's your goal, you'd probably have `A` set an instance of `B` as its delegate early on, probably in it's `-init` (or other initializer).

Comment: Thanks, so It's better to use the first one always. I wasn't init the view by coding. I was using storyboard to drag the view out and set it to a subclass of UIviewController, so I should put setDelegate in viewDidLoad,right? But I didn't get what I was expecting. :(

Comment: Given that you need 2 views to communicate to each other. I would change a model object instead of delegation. If Delegation is a must, then check if your views are using the same delegate object.

Comment: @RobertD'Almeida I agree -- the OP doesn't give a reason for using delegation, and the fact that both classes are views is pretty suspicious.